# Guava Immutable version of LinkedHashMultimap?

Tags: java, guava, immutability, multimap

I want to create an immutable version of LinkedHashMultiMap. I can roll my own using ImmutableMap and ImmutableList but wondering if there is a way to extend Guava to do it.  For example, using Forwarding or Supplier.

Comment: Why not just use [`ImmutableListMultimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableListMultimap.html)?

Comment: Would [`MultiMaps.unmodifiableMultimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear whether you want a `ListMultimap` or a `SetMultimap`, but you almost certainly want `ImmutableListMultimap` and `ImmutableSetMultimap` respectively in any event.  Like all immutable collections, it'll still preserve insertion order exactly like `LinkedHashMultimap`.

Guava's immutable collections are very deliberately not extensible.

Comment: I can't tell if that was a question.

Comment: It was just a link to Guava doc stating the insertion order is preserved.  I do not know why there is "?" at the end.

Comment: @mjlee: I guess I do. You were linking to the anchor `How?` and somehow the question mark ran out of your link; [this link](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained#How?) is right.